# build VS2010 project with TFS2008 build server

Tags: testing, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

is it somehow possible to run tests with it?

I am always getting message:
(CoreTestConfiguration target) -> 
  MSBUILD : warning : Visual Studio Team System for Software Testers or Visual Studio Team System for Software Developers is required to run tests as part of a Team Build.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible, we have such configuration (VS2010 project and TFS2008 where we store it). Probably when you set up the build on build server you have chosen to run the tests with this build - so please install proper Visual Studio version (Visual Studio Team System for Software Testers or Visual Studio Team System for Software Developers) on the Build Machine. Or setup the build without test option.